# How can I debug missing menu clicks?

Tags: unity, mouse, menu, debugging

After turning on the option "Show menus in the window's title bar" I'm intermittently experiencing an issue where clicking (left-click) on an application menu has no effect (i.e. the menu does not drop down).  This seems to happen with any application and I've seen it since at least Ubuntu 16.04.  I've [posted a screen recording to YouTube](https://youtu.be/qfB-W7JRlxg) so you can see what happens when I click.  Usually moving the mouse around will cause it to succeed eventually but there doesn't seem to be any consistent place in the menu where the click works.

The screen recording was with a clean install of 16.10 on a 2016 Dell XPS 13.

I'm at a loss for how to debug the issue any further so and suggestions would be welcome.

Comment: One additional data point.  This seems to happen when the Appearance -> Behavior setting **Show the menus for a window in the window's title bar** option is selected.

Comment: I haven't tried a wired mouse but the behavior is the same with an external bluetooth mouse and the integrated trackpad.

Comment: Problem exists with a wired mouse and a Logitech Unify mouse.  The problem seems to be rooted in the option to "Show menus in the window's title bar".